# Given error of distance, and the error of angle, How would I set a percentage of motion attributed to angular motion, and the net speed

Tags: math, robotics

So I have a robot with a mecanum drive, meaning it can move in any direction. I am trying to program it to move to a point and reach that point at a given angle, all while moving in a straight line. So far I've gotten the robot to reach that point, I've gotten it to stay on the straight line, but I cant get it to reach the correct angle(without having it turn and then move). To simplify the movement, I have a function that I creatively called Move, Move takes in three floats:

The first is what angle the robot moves to relative to the robots angle, but ignore this one as I got it working

the second(angle%) determines the percentage of motion that is given to the angular motion, so when it is given 1, the robot will only be turning, and when it is given 0, it won't turn at all. At 0.5 it will be turning a bit, and moving towards the destination at the same time.

The last one is the speed the robot moves at ranging from 0-127. For this I will probably use two PID loops, one for the angle error, and one for the distance error, then add both up.

So my problem is finding an algorithm to find what I should set angle% to, in order to arrive at a point facing the right way. There are a few 'properties that angle% must have: if distance = 0, and angle error > 0, angle% should = 1. And if distance > 0 and angle error = 0. Also when the angle err is 180deg, angle % should = 1.

I know the solution is going to be really simple but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: how many joint your robot has ?  what are the minimum/maximum angle of rotation of each joint?   Of course, every single point in the work area can be reached in various ways (angles combinations). Perhaps a solution may be to calculate all possible rotations of all joints and save the achievable point for each combination of rotations. Once, forever. So with a database system ask for a particular point and get all the solutions for that point. In the end choose the most convenient solution for that point.